# Trying to add every single number within a range using a for loop to create a sum

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addition

I can't figure out the issue with my code. The output should add every number in a range (like 1 and 2 when entered will output 3). However, 1 and 3 outputs 12 for no discernible reason.

```
function Sum(){
        var int1=document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
        var int2=document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
        for(i=int1; i<=int2; i++){
            var total=int1;
            total+=i;
            if(i==int2){
                alert("The sum of all numbers is "+total);
            }
        }
}
```

```js
    
        function Sum(){
         var int1=document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
         var int2=document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
         for(i=int1; i<=int2; i++){
          var total=int1;
          total+=i;
             if(i==int2){
                 alert("The sum of all numbers is "+total);
             }
         }
        }
```

```html
    
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>
        For Sum Exercise
        </title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>
        </script>
        User Number 1:<input id="TextBox1"><br><br>
        User Number 2:<input id="TextBox2"><br><br>
        <button onClick="Sum()">Sum</button><br>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Try parsing your values into Integers using the `parseInt` function. For example: `parseInt(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;`.

Comment: Use parseInt method for your variables int1 and int2

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a number from the input. `value` is from type string. With an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), you get a number.

You need to declare `i` as well.

Declare `total` in advance and take zero as value outside of the loop.

After the loop make the output.

```js
function Sum() {
    var int1 = +document.getElementById("TextBox1").value,
        int2 = +document.getElementById("TextBox2").value,
        total = 0,
        i;

    for (var i = int1; i <= int2; i++) {
        total += i;
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = "The sum of all numbers is " + total;
}
```

```html
User Number 1: <input id="TextBox1"><br><br> User Number 2: <input id="TextBox2"><br><br>
<button onClick="Sum()">Sum</button><br>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

Comment: upvote for `With an unary plus +, you get a number.`